# ServiceNow SNC - Find Underlying Report SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, servicenow

Is there a way to locate the underlying SQL in a ServiceNow (SNC) instance using MySQL as the database platform?  My user account doesn't have access to watch the PROCESSLIST, so I was looking for a table possibly that stored an SNC based report's SQL.

For example, I've created a report in SNC and execute it manually.  I would like to be able to go out to some table in the database to see if the SQL for which that report is based upon is available outside of watching the PROCESSLIST.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the question of "why?" (normal hosted instances don't expose direct database connectivity to end users, so I'm curious what you plan to do with the raw sql), you can get the sql that was used anywhere in the platform by activating sql debugging. This requires the `admin` role in the appliation.

To activate sql debugging, in the left nav, go to **`System Diagnostics > Session Debug > Debug SQL`**

This will cause sql statements for every transaction **in your session** to be written to the bottom of every page load. It *also* includes the sql for the previous transaction, so if you need to get the sql for an AJAX transaction or something, just trigger it, and then navigate to some other page (`/ui_page.do` is an easy one that doesn't load anything, but still gives you your sql debug output)